# Is possible to display jquery popup meanwhile onbeforeunload trigger call?

Tags: jquery, popup, window, onbeforeunload

Is this possible to open jquery popup when onbeforeunload event call?

Please check in image url here I have html content with one button and google link. Now when I click on tab or window close I need to display jquery popup under window confirmation box for leave or stay on page.

http://staging.jigmogroup.com/dvs/win_confirm.png

Finally I made solution Here:

I got solution its possible we can able to call javascript function not jquery. like

```
var leave_message = 'You sure you want to leave?'
function goodbye() {

    //load popup
    loadPopup();
    centerPopup();

    return leave_message;
}
window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;
```

We can able to call javascript function not jquery so its working

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible.

`onbeforeunload` can only return a string that is alerted in a native browser alert window and gives the user the option to continue or not.  In fact, Firefox won't even print out this string.

Comment: I got solution its possible we can able to call javascript function not jquery. like

var leave_message = 'You sure you want to leave?'
        function goodbye() {
                //load popup
                loadPopup();
                centerPopup();
                                    
                //return works for Chrome and Safari
                return leave_message;
         
        }
        window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;

If that function have jquery code then its not working

Comment: @DivyeshBhalodi you can do this with jQuery to: `$(window).on('beforeunload' ...)`

Comment: Yes, We can call onbeforeunload in jquery But we can't able to call jquery meanwhile displaying confirmation alert this time only javascript is allow. like loadPopup(); in this function only js code is working, not work jquery code